# How to load a jar from an URL without downloading it?

Tags: class, url, jar, download, load

JAVA - Well just that, i know how to load external jars from my main project with classloader and even download a jar from an url and load it, but there's anyway to load a jar from a url without dowloading? just load it in memory from the url to use it? thanks!

Comment: Is [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) not working for you?

Comment: Yea but can't use the jar without download it, has any idea on how to access the jar classes in an url without download it?

Comment: Solved by myself thanks anyway guys.

Comment: How did you solve it?